# solving a quadratic equation with matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, quadratic

I'm trying to numerically find the solution to `X^2+X+C=0` where C is the matrix `C=[-6,-5;0,-6]` and `0=[0,0;0,0]`, a quadratic equation where the variable is 2x2 matrix.

So I wrote the following matlab commands

```
C=[-6,-5;0,-6]
[X1,F,e_flag]=fsolve('X^2+X+C',[1,1;1,1])
```

where `[1,1;1,1]` is our initial estimate, or `X0`.

I'm getting the following errors

"Error using inlineeval (line 15)
Error in inline expression ==> X^2+X+C
 Undefined function or variable 'X'.

Error in inline/feval (line 34)
        INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr,
        INLINE_OBJ_.expr);

Error in fsolve (line 218)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE
    cannot continue."

How do I use fsolve to solve these kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `fsolve` can be used with a string representation of your equation.
You should rather pass a function handle to the solver like this:

```
C = [-6,-5;0,-6];
[X1,F,e_flag] = fsolve(@(X) X^2+X+C,[1,1;1,1]);
```

It also depends on what you mean by: `X^2`. In Matlab this means the matrix product `X*X`. If you want entry-wise squaring you should use `X.^2`, in which case you will have four independent quadratic equations, which you could solve independently.

Comment: I meant X*X so X^2 was correct. and indeed that solved the problem. Should have used a function handle.

Comment: By the way: This could be solved with a simple Newton iteration, if `fsolve` isn't fast enough for you.